# pandas iterate over rows based on column values

Tags: pandas, loops

I want to calculate the temperature difference at the same time between to cities. The data structure looks as follows:

```
dic = {'city':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b'],'week':[1,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,7],'temp':[20,21,23,21,25,20,21,24,21,22]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df
+------+------+------+
| city | week | temp |
+------+------+------+
| a    |    1 |   20 |
| a    |    2 |   21 |
| a    |    3 |   23 |
| a    |    4 |   21 |
| a    |    5 |   25 |
| b    |    3 |   20 |
| b    |    4 |   21 |
| b    |    5 |   24 |
| b    |    6 |   21 |
| b    |    7 |   22 |
+------+------+------+
```

I would like to calculate the difference in temperature between city a and b at week 3, 4, and 5. The final data structure should look as follows:

```
+--------+-------+------+------+
| city_1 | city2 | week | diff |
+--------+-------+------+------+
| a      | b     |    3 |    3 |
| a      | b     |    4 |    0 |
| a      | b     |    5 |    1 |
+--------+-------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pivot your data, drop the NA values, and do the subtraction directly. This way you can keep the source temperatures associated with each city.

```py
result = (
    df.pivot(index='week', columns='city', values='temp')
      .dropna(how='any', axis='index')
      .assign(diff=lambda df: df['a'] - df['b'])  
)
print(result)
```

```
city     a     b  diff
week                  
3     23.0  20.0   3.0
4     21.0  21.0   0.0
5     25.0  24.0   1.0
```

Comment: Just a play on your answer : ``(
    df.pivot(index='week', columns='city', values='temp')
      .dropna(how='any', axis='index')
      .assign(diff=lambda df : df.agg(np.subtract.reduce, axis=1))  
)``

Comment: @sammywemmy what happens with your version if there's a "C" city too?

Comment: it applies it as well. it builds off with the same idea as reduce in functools. so, you'll have ``df.a - df.b - df.c``, since it is applying it across the columns

Comment: @sammywemmy so probably not a good operation for comparing temperatures in cites

Comment: this question is not comparing temperatures, is it? from what i understand, it is getting the difference in the temperatures. reduction would be irrelevant for comparisons

Comment: @sammywemmy the first sentence of the question is: *want to calculate the temperature difference at the same time between to*  [sic] *cities*

Comment: sorry guys, there are some typoes that are misleading. Yes, the purpose is to calculate the difference in temperature in two cities. And, the 'city2' should be 'city_2"